# SQLite+Qt: Select from table always returns single row

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, qtsql, qsqlquery

I use the following piece of code to fetch data from SQLite DB using Qt:

```
QSqlQuery wordQuery( QString( "SELECT id, word FROM Words WHERE ref_id = :ref_id" ) );
wordQuery.bindValue( ":ref_id", refId );
wordQuery.setForwardOnly( true );
wordQuery.exec( );

while( wordQuery.next( ) ) {
    // obtain data from `wordQuery` using QSqlQuery::value( )
}
```

The `Words` table do contain rows with `ref_id` field equal to needed value. I've checked this with sqlbrowser supplied as Qt demo application. But `QSqlQuery::next( )` returns true only the first time and I cannot fetch rest of rows.

BTW, here I found [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066315/qsqlquery-for-sqlite-in-forward-iteration-with-next-will-only-find-one-row) but for me backward iteration doesn't work

Below I put the whole function code:

```
QList<Word> LyricsMasterModel::fetchWords( const DbId &refId )
{
QList<Word> result;

if ( !db.isOpen( ) && !db.open( ) ) {
    return result;
}

QSqlQuery wordQuery;
wordQuery.setForwardOnly( true );
wordQuery.prepare( QString( "SELECT id, word FROM %1 WHERE ref_id = :ref_id" )
    .arg( WORDS_TABLE_NAME ) );
wordQuery.bindValue( ":ref_id", refId );
if ( !wordQuery.exec( ) ) {
    qDebug( ) << "SQL QUERY ERROR:" << wordQuery.lastError( ).text( );
}

const QSqlRecord wordTuple = wordQuery.record( );
const int idIndex = wordTuple.indexOf( "id" );
Q_ASSERT( -1 != idIndex );
const int wordIndex = wordTuple.indexOf( "word" );
Q_ASSERT( -1 != wordIndex );

while (wordQuery.next()) {
    Word word;

    word.setId( wordQuery.value( idIndex ).toByteArray( ) );
    word.setSongId( refId );
    word.setWord( wordQuery.value( wordIndex ).toString( ) );

    result << word;
}

db.close( );
return result;
}
```

**Solution:** I didn't manage to find the reason of the problem, but the following variant appeared to be the working one:

```
QSqlQuery wordQuery;
wordQuery.prepare( QString( "SELECT id, word FROM %1 WHERE ref_id = :ref_id" )
    .arg( WORDS_TABLE_NAME ) );
wordQuery.bindValue( ":ref_id", refId );
const bool res = wordQuery.exec( );
Q_ASSERT( res );

if ( wordQuery.last( ) ) {
    do {
        // do stuff
    } while (wordQuery.previous());
}
```

Comment: @LaszloPapp, no, I wasn't. But if I use `wordQuery.exec( "SELECT id, word FROM Words WHERE ref_id = 1" );` and set the `ref_id` parameter inside the query string there is no result rows at all, i.e. `QSqlQuery::next( )` returns false on the first call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has one major issue for the binding, namely:

> [QSqlQuery::QSqlQuery(const QString & query = QString(), QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase())](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#QSqlQuery-2)
>
> Constructs a QSqlQuery object using the SQL query and the database db. If db is not specified, or is invalid, the application's default database is used. If query is not an empty string, it will be executed.

So, your query will be executed during the construction since it is not empty, and the bind is already too late for that.

I would personally construct the instance with an empty string as the default, and then do an explicit preparation as per [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#prepare).

So, I would write something like this:

```
QSqlQuery wordQuery();
wordQuery.setForwardOnly(true);
wordQuery.prepare("SELECT id, word FROM Words WHERE ref_id = :ref_id");
wordQuery.bindValue(":ref_id", refId);
if (!wordQuery.exec())
    qDebug() << "SQL QUERY ERROR:" << wordQuery.lastError().text();

while (wordQuery.next()) {
    // obtain data from `wordQuery` using QSqlQuery::value( )
}
```

Comment: It still returns a single row:(

Comment: @Ivan: you mean you do not get any errors and the exec() succeeds fine with true? Can you show your refId and the rows that you expect to be returned? Can you also show the internals of your while loop? The error must be somewhere else, not in this code...

Comment: @Ivan: let me repeat the third time, please tell us if the exec succeeds, and if not, let us know the error message. Also, the record snippet is moot because value() can take a string just fine.

Comment: `exec()` returns true

Comment: @Ivan: as already asked, what is the refId? What happens if you hard code it rather than binding? Can you show your rows to see if they are right, or at least the code, if any, that inserts the rows?

Comment: BTW, in Qt 4.8.4 `value( )` cannot take string as input (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsqlquery.html#value). As I wrote in the comment to the question if I hardcode the `refId` value like this: `SELECT id, word FROM Words WHERE ref_id = 1` `exec( )` still returns true but `next( )` does not returns true in for the first time, i.e. I cannot get any rows at all.

Comment: Right, you have not mentioned Qt 4, and the default assumption is Qt 5 these days. Either way, show what you insert into the database table.

Comment: The table `Words` has three columns: "id", "ref_id", "word". Content is: (1, 1, "lkjlkj;"), (2, 1, "lkjlkjlk"), (3, 1, "asdasd"), (4, 2, "sdfsdgdfg"), (5, 2, "gdfjgl"), (6, 2, "dfgkl;g")

Comment: @Ivan: have you checked if the query worked with the sqlite command line or any other client for your database table? Just in case...

Comment: Yes, I've checked and result is confusing: the query `SELECT id, word FROM Words WHERE ref_id = 1` returns nothing but other queries (like `select *`, `select * where id = 1`) return what is expected

Comment: Right, so your problem is not actually with the Qt code since even an sqlite execute for the query does not work as you expect... Are you sure you have not made any typo? Anyway, this sounds like a voodoo, so please paste a self-contained code that I can run manually and test it. It really should not be this hard.

Comment: I didn't find the solution, but I found some dumb workaround instead (See the question). And since it works, the problem is rather in Qt's implementation than in my queries.

Comment: @Ivan: what happens if you drop `wordQuery.setForwardOnly(true);` from my code? You refuse to provide a self-contained snippet, and you blame Qt? :)